# Application.Caller object required error

Tags: excel, vba

How to get current sheet (not activesheet) name from function? By "current sheet" I mean sheet name where function placed and called from.

I trying get like that

```
Function MySheet()

   MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
MsgBox MySheet
End Function
```

but i get error object required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to be careful in how you call that function. You've supplied very little detail on what you want to do with it.

```
Function MySheet()
    Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
        Case "Range"
            MySheet = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
        Case "String"
            MySheet = Application.Caller
        Case "Error"
            MySheet = "Error"
        Case Else
            MySheet = "unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

Th above at least attempts to make some sort of determination of what `Application.Caller` is before using it to determine the associated worksheet object's name.

You can read more at [Application.Caller Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx).

Comment: What are the "String" and "Error" cases for? Can the caller ever be a String??

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - According to the MSDN doc I linked to *"An Auto_Open, Auto_Close, Auto_Activate, or Auto_Deactivate macro"* returns *"The name of the document as text"* and *"A macro set by either the OnDoubleClick or OnEntry property"* returns *"The name of the chart object identifier or cell reference (if applicable) to which the macro applies"*.

Comment: Aha, but a `Function` isn't a macro. It can't be assigned to a chart or called in any of those other ways you list. Only `Case "Range"` will ever apply; as it stands, the rest is dead code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - The original question has been clarified with an edit but I was trying to cover many possible methods. TBH, I don't know offhand what would happen if the function was called from within an `Auto_Open` macro but wanted to cover as many bases as I reasonably could.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Actually a function can be assigned as a macro to any shape - you just have to type its name into the macro dialog. And in such a case, `Application.Caller` is indeed a string. ;) However, if you assign it using `Application.OnDoubleClick` for example, you actually get a Range object, not a String.

Answer (score 1):

[Is it `Me` you're looking for?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_ILDFp5DGA)

```
MsgBox Me.Name
```

This is what you want if by "sheet name where function placed" you mean, the Sheet module in which the function code is placed. ([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251792.aspx)).

However, if you mean, the sheet containing the cell from which the user-defined function is called, you can use:

```
MsgBox Application.Caller.Parent.Name
```

`Application.Caller` returns a `Range` object referring to the cell; this range's `Parent` is then the sheet.

Comment: This solved my problem of getting the sheet name the macro is attached to, I don't know why it got downvoted.